# Issue in awk if statement

Tags: if-statement, awk, syntax

I seem to be not getting this awk statement right:

```
awk '{ trailing=""; if ($0 ~ / /) trailing="#"; printf("# %s\n#elements/%s%s\n", $0, $0, trailing) > $0".txt" }' file
```

I am getting this error:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
    { trailing=""; if ($0 ~ / /) trailing="#"; printf("# %s\n#elements/%s%s\n", $0, $0, trailing) > >>>  $0".txt" <<<
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
```

What's wrong here?  I tried putting `{ }` around the single statement in the if block but it didn't help.

Comment: Not the problem in question but FYI `trailing=""; if ($0 ~ / /) trailing="#"` is equivalent to `trailing=(/ / ? "#" : "")`. Also since you're not using GNU awk your script will fail with a "too many open files" error once you get past about 20 unique input lines - let us know if that's an issue you need help with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since source Input_file is not posted so couldn't test it, could you please try wrapping `$0".txt"` as `($0".txt")` as follows and let me know then.

```
awk '{ trailing=""; if ($0 ~ / /) trailing="#"; printf("# %s\n#elements/%s%s\n", $0, $0, trailing) > ($0".txt") }' Input_file
```

Comment: That did it.  I wonder why we need a `()` around that string expression.

Comment: @codeforester how an unparenthesized expression on the right side of input or output redirection should be interpreted is undefined behavior per POSIX. So given `print > foo bar` an awk can interpret that as `print > (foo bar)` as you'd like in this case but it can also interpret it as `(print > foo) bar` as this particular awk did and so gave a syntax error and still be POSIX compliant. Just always parenthesize any expression on the right side of input or output redirection for portability (and it also helps clarity so doing that is a win-win).